# JQuery hide and show doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have been trying to make a updateable grid.Which means i show an icon on mouseover
on click of that icon i show a new row with textboxes and hide the previous row then there is a an icon which saves the values using ajax.On Successfull completion of this ajax save process i make a new row of the data and replace the previous row with textboxes.

Problem is that i cant run mouseovers and other function using jQuery selectors as the newly replaced html will not be binded to it.I did a workaround for that i was calling:

```
jQuery('[rel="datepicker"]').datepicker();
          jQuery('[rel="innerRows"]').mouseover(function (){
          //alert('hererere');
            var spanId = jQuery(this).attr('spanid');
            jQuery('[rel="innerSpans"]').hide();
            jQuery('#edit_'+spanId).show();
          });
          jQuery('[rel="editButton"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('#show_'+recordId).hide();
            jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).show();
          });
          jQuery('[rel="saveRecord"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('recId');
            var event    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#event_'+recordId).val());
            var date     = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#date_'+recordId).val());
            var location = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#location_'+recordId).val());
            var notes    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#notes_'+recordId).val());
            if(event !='' && date !='' && location !='' && notes !=''){
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url:'/application/saveevent/',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: '&recId='+recordId+'&event='+event+'&date='+date+'&location='+location+'&notes='+notes,
                  success : function (text){
                    jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).replaceWith(text);
                    bind();
                  } 
              });
            }
```

to show and save the row.Now in the bind function i am again calling the above script to rebind the new html with jQuery selectors.

Problem is that in this bind function

```
 jQuery('[rel="innerSpans"]').hide();
            jQuery('#edit_'+spanId).show();
```

Doesnt work it does not show or hide the button inside the generated html
It is to show and hide the edit icons in the generated html which it doesnt.
Is it because of the element is in replaced html or what.
Please suggest.

This is the HTML.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="eventsTableEdit">
                              <tbody><tr class="headeventtbl">
                                <td width="280" class="">Event</td>
                                <td width="160" class="">Date</td>
                                <td width="200">Location</td>
                                <td width="200">Notes</td>
                              </tr>
                                                            <tr id="show_6" spanid="6" rel="innerRows" class="odd">
                                <td class=""><span id="edit_6" style="display: inline;" rel="innerSpans"><a id="6" rel="editButton" href="javascript:void(0)"><img title="Click here to edit." alt="Click here to edit." src="/img/edit.png"></a></span>event of councils</td>
                                <td class="">02/08/2012</td>
                                <td>Canada</td>
                                <td class="">Call them</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr id="hid_6" style="display:none;">
                                <td><span id="save_6"><a recid="6" rel="saveRecord" href="javascript:void(0)"><img title="Click here to save." alt="Click here to save." src="/img/save.png"></a></span><input type="text" value="event of councils" id="event_6" name="data[event]"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="02/08/2012" rel="datepicker" id="date_6" name="data[date]" class="hasDatepicker"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="Canada" id="location_6" name="data[location]"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="Call them" id="notes_6" name="data[notes]"></td>
                              </tr>
                                                            <tr id="show_7" spanid="7" rel="innerRows" class="odd">
                                <td class=""><span id="edit_7" style="display: none;" rel="innerSpans"><a id="7" rel="editButton" href="javascript:void(0)"><img title="Click here to edit." alt="Click here to edit." src="/img/edit.png"></a></span>eventssssss</td>
                                <td>03/07/2012</td>
                                <td>Restaurant</td>
                                <td>Notes are here</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr id="hid_7" style="display:none;">
                                <td><span id="save_7"><a recid="7" rel="saveRecord" href="javascript:void(0)"><img title="Click here to save." alt="Click here to save." src="/img/save.png"></a></span><input type="text" value="eventssssss" id="event_7" name="data[event]"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="03/07/2012" rel="datepicker" id="date_7" name="data[date]" class="hasDatepicker"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="Restaurant" id="location_7" name="data[location]"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="Notes are here" id="notes_7" name="data[notes]"></td>
                              </tr>

                            </tbody></table>
```

I replace the row with a new row which is updated.http://203.100.79.84:9733/

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: I think you will have to post the HTML for us to understand enough to help.

Comment: I have edited the html in the question.Please have a look.

Comment: do you have any css out there that is using the !important setting? If you have something like "display:none !important;" in there, you're not going to be able to use show() with effect.

Comment: @Christopher No there is no such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `on()` instead of `mouseover()`?

E.g:

```
jQuery('[rel="innerRows"]').on("mouseover", function (){

    var spanId = jQuery(this).attr('spanid');
    jQuery('[rel="innerSpans"]').hide();
    jQuery('#edit_'+spanId).show();
 });
```

Comment: yet .show() is a simple jQuery method that on its own is unlikely to go wrong, so something else must be affecting it. Does the jQuery('#edit_'+spanId) selector actually select an element? is spanId the correct value?

Comment: Yes all is correct if i alert(jQuery('#edit_'+spanId)).attr('id'); it gives me the proper ID of the element.But somehow doesnt sets it up to show.